# CHAR_AT function ends up with special characters

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I execute the below query, I am getting '#' values for some records in some columns. These columns use TO_CHAR function to round off the values to 2 or 4 decimal places and after adding the TO_CHAR function the values are displayed as below.

[image]

I suspect that this has something to do with the column size but not sure where to modify. I am using Oracle SQL Developer.

Any idea on this is very much appreciated.

Comment: That means the value could not be converted using the normber format model provider without overflow/truncation. When you see that, you should revise your number format model so it can cover those values. In your case it appears that your multiplication sometimes exceeds 2 digits left of the decimal point, so you must allow for that.

Comment: Hi - please don’t paste images as no-one can copy your SQL/data if they want to try out a solution. Also, the title of your question mentions CHAR_AT but your actual question is talking about TO_CHAR

Comment: Your format model is `fm99D00` but the value you are trying to display is greater than `99.99`. Change your format model to `fm999D00` if your maximum value is `999.99` or add more `9`s for larger numbers.